# buyback token with uniswap-v3

Tags: solidity, contract-development, uniswap, hardhat, uniswapv3

I write a smart contract can buyback a specific token **with the contract balance ETH**, however I have the tx error `Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'STF'` (error in the transfert).

```
    contract Buyback {
    ...
    
    function _buyBack(uint256 amount) private {
            console.log("amount buy: %s", amount);
            // work but not take eth of user
            // TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(
            //     WETH,
            //     msg.sender, // danger
            //     address(this),
            //     amount
            // );
            // TransferHelper.safeApprove(WETH, router, amount);
    
    
            ISwapRouter.ExactInputSingleParams memory params = ISwapRouter
                .ExactInputSingleParams({
                    tokenIn: WETH,
                    tokenOut: tokenToBuy,
                    fee: poolFee,
                    recipient: address(this),
                    deadline: block.timestamp + 300,
                    amountIn: amount,
                    amountOutMinimum: 0,
                    sqrtPriceLimitX96: 0
                });
            ISwapRouter(router).exactInputSingle(params);
        }

}
```

what do I need to do for the pass transaction?

Comment: Does the contract have enough WETH? Has it approved the router?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to use ETH you need to include the value in the call

ISwapRouter(router).exactInputSingle{value:Amount}(params);